# Replace ModelChoiceField with auto suggest textfield with same queryset

Tags: django, autosuggest

I have a `ModelChoiceField` in django forms:

```
customField  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.filter(type="sometype"))
```

But this queryset returns thousands of rows, effectively choking customField in the admin interface. Instead, I need an autosuggest text field there, which will perform a `like '%keystrokes%'` query on above queryset. I feel this is a better option. I need a very basic auto-suggest, no fancy css. Is there any implicit support for this in django? I went through django autosuggest plugins, but they were very complex.

Can I tie it with django's core field types, like: `models.ForeignKey('MyModel')`, similarly, `models.AutosuggestField('MyModel')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this

- django-autocomplete - jquery AutoComplete for ForeignKey & ManyToManyField - Google Project Hosting -> http://code.google.com/p/django-autocomplete/

for admin you can have auto complete